# Unable to access custom plugin backend

Tags: plugin-development, capabilities, permissions

So, I just created a new plugin and i've added capabilities, a new role, linked them all together, etc.. etc.. but for some reason I'm unable to access my own backend.

Error message is the generic

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

Code to create the Menu on the backend

```
add_menu_page(
    'FOO Profile',                // Link Text
    'Manage your FOO profile',    // Title
    'foo-profile',                // Capability (rights)
    'foo-profile',                // Slug
    [$this, 'renderFooProfile']   // Callback for Link
);
```

This link is VISIABLE to me inside the admin area. I did the following check just to verify on top of this:

```
var_dump(current_user_can('foo-profile')) => int(1)
```

Now once i click the link i get the above-mentioned error message.

The rendering is a simple hello world echo, so I doubt the error is to be found there either :S

```
public function renderFooProfile() { echo "Hello World"; }
```

Any pointers as to where I'd have to look would be greatly appreciated.

Gist of the whole class > https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b4f69e203630f447677b

Comment: Can you post the class/containing code

Comment: @TheDeadMedic sure thing > https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b4f69e203630f447677b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `admin_init` hook to add menus - use `admin_menu` instead.

The init hook runs early enough for `wp-admin/menu.php` to add it to the sidebar menu, but not for the plugin page loading in `wp-admin/admin.php`

In other words, when you actually try to load the plugin page, your menu code hasn't fired and WordPress fails with that rather generic error.

Comment: Too simple Xx Thank you a lot. Could you elaborate as to why the menu is still displayed using `admin_init` but then being inaccessible?

Comment: Check revision.